# Servlet using Controller Annotation

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

Unable to go to Servlet from hello.jsp to MainController Class. This is a maven project.

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    
    @Controller
    public class MainController {
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcome() {
            return "Hello";
    
        }
        @RequestMapping("displayname")
        public String displayName(HttpServletRequest request) {
            System.out.println("Working till here");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            request.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
            return "displayName";
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Question is not clear so I can only recommend that response.redirect can be used.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am unable to send request to class MainController.java from hello.jsp

Comment: hello.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Please enter your name: 
<form action="displayName">
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<input type="submit" value ="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: You are sending post request to Controller but your controller is receiving only GET request

Answer (score 0):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/displayname", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String displayName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Working till here");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        request.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
        return "displayName";
    }
```

You can change method parameter on requestmapping annotation. Also you can get body in displayName method and redirect it. I checked that method is empty when it is not defined. Maybe you can use @PostMapping annotation and other annotations like @GetMapping, @PostMapping etc...